# MOSFET to be switched by a raspberry pi

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi

My raspberry pi produces a 3.3V on it's GPIO. I want to buy a through hole MOSFET so I can simulate touch-events on a smartphone screen like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGFZkrMoFo0&google_comment_id=z13bgdxrlp3uchdan04cc5woozyzjj0xvpc0k). I'm trying to find something on Digi-Key, but I'm not sure how to choose the right component other than VDD needs to include 3.3 or 5V. Suggestions? (Can you explain how you picked the part.)

Comment: What you are looking for is a MOSFET with low gate threshold voltage. The best bet is looking for parts designed for low voltage switching regulators, which tend to have low max. source-drain voltages (e.g. 20 V) as well.

Comment: Thru hole is silly, and will severly limit your choice of parts.  You need to keep up with the 1990s.